# Sending message on glassfish server message queue

Tags: glassfish, jms

I am just testing to send the message on glassfish server queue so for that i have created JMSResource on glassfish server like this :

[image]

And now i have created one java application in Netbeans IDE. This is my Java File :-

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;  
   import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

public class MessageSender
{
  @Resource(mappedName = "jms/ConnectionFactory")
  private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
  @Resource(mappedName = "jms/Queue")
  private static Queue queue;

  public void produceMessages()
  {
    MessageProducer messageProducer;
    TextMessage textMessage;
    try
    {
      Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
      Session session = connection.createSession(false,
        Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      messageProducer = session.createProducer(queue);
      textMessage = session.createTextMessage();

      textMessage.setText("Testing, 1, 2, 3. Can you hear me?");
      System.out.println("Sending the following message: "
        + textMessage.getText());
      messageProducer.send(textMessage);

      messageProducer.close();
      session.close();
      connection.close();
    }
    catch (JMSException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new MessageSender().produceMessages();
  }
}
```

Now, when i run this simple application then it is giving error on create ConnectionFactory:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at simplesendamq.MessageSender.produceMessages(MessageSender.java:33)
    at simplesendamq.MessageSender.main(MessageSender.java:55)
```

Comment: Line 33 in above code is blank line (line 33 supposed to be a line where NullPointerException happened). Please post exact code as in your application. One other thing - what kind of project did you put your class in? Enterprise application client or something else?

Answer (score 0):

GF clients had to use JNDI-look up to obtain connection factory
and message destinations (topic/queue).

So, you had to form JNDI-context (where you set host, ORB port, other magic params) and include in classpath certain libraries (it requied to work with GF).

My example:

**Receiver.java**

```
    import javax.jms.*;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import java.util.Properties;

    public class Receiver implements MessageListener {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, NamingException {
            try {
                Properties props = new Properties();

                props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",
                                  "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
                props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs",
                                  "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
                props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state",
                                  "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
                props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
                props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");

                // Gets the JNDI context
                Context jndiContext = new InitialContext(props);

                // Looks up the administered objects
                ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)
                        jndiContext.lookup("my.connection.factory");

                Queue queue = (Queue) jndiContext.lookup("my.test.queue");

                // Creates the needed artifacts to connect to the queue
                Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

                Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

                MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);

                connection.start();   

            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

     @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println("onMsg!");
    }
    }
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>examples.my</groupId>
    <artifactId>jms-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.messaging</groupId>
            <artifactId>imqjmsra</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-rev-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-util</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.appclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>gf-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-b74b</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.appclient.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>appclient-server-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-b74b</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.corba</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-corba-orb</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1-b001</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>security</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-b74b</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```